# Getting $media all the time with values

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have this code for move inside arrays and build a proper JSON response but something is not working since `$media` got always the same values and shouldn't be cause in the 2nd iteration there are not `$media`. What is wrong in my logic? Any advice?

**Code snippet**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($entEmail); $i++) {
    $entMedia = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getAllEmailsMedia($entEmail[$i]['id']);

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($entMedia); $j++) {
        $media[] = [
            "media_id" => $entMedia[$j]['id'],
            "title" => $entMedia[$j]['title'],
            "description" => $entMedia[$j]['description'],
            "thumbnail_url" => $entMedia[$j]['thumbnail_url'],
            "viewedAt" => $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getMediaViewedAt($entEmail[$i]['id'], $entMedia[$j]['id']) ? $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getMediaViewedAt($entEmail[$i]['id'], $entMedia[$j]['id']) : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        ];
    }

    $response[] = [
        "id" => $entEmail[$i]['id'],
        "rep_id" => $entEmail[$i]['reps_id'],
        "target_id" => $entEmail[$i]['targets_id'],
        "brands_id" => $entEmail[$i]['brands_id'],
        "brand_name" => $entEmail[$i]['name'],
        "messages_id" => $entEmail[$i]['messages_id'],
        "message_text" => $entEmail[$i]['message_text'],
        "media" => $media,
        "category" => $entEmail[$i]['category'],
        "createdAt" => $entEmail[$i]['createdAt'],
        "openedAt" => $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getEmailOpenetAt($entEmail[$i]['id']) ? $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getEmailOpenetAt($entEmail[$i]['id']) : "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "viewedAt" => $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getEmailViewedAt($entEmail[$i]['id']) ? $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getEmailViewedAt($entEmail[$i]['id']) : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ];
}
```

**Current Response**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "rep_id": "1",
    "target_id": "1",
    "brands_id": "1",
    "brand_name": "Combivent Respimat",
    "messages_id": "1",
    "message_text": "Dear [HCP Name],  Thank you for taking the time to speak with me today.  Based on our discussion, I’ve attached additional materials about COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.  I look forward to speaking with you again in the near future.",
    "media": [
      {
        "media_id": "1",
        "title": "Abbreviated Visual Aid",
        "description": "Provides information on key features of COMBIVENT RESPIMAT, including safety and efficacy information, the RESPIMAT Inhaler.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/abbreviated_vis_aid.png",
        "viewedAt": "2015-05-24 23:27:41"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "2",
        "title": "Solutions Plus™ HCP Flashcard",
        "description": "Information about the Solutions Plus phone line that offers support services and education to both patients and HCPs.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/sp_flash_card.png",
        "viewedAt": "2015-05-24 23:27:42"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "3",
        "title": "Solutions Plus™ Patient Flashcard",
        "description": "A detailed list of the services Solutions Plus offers to patients that you can print and give to patients together with a prescription for COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/sp_patient_card.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "4",
        "title": "Abbreviated Instructions for Use",
        "description": "A step-by-step patient guide listing the steps for COMBIVENT RESPIMAT preparation, priming, and dosing, with information on safety and important features of COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/patient_tearsheet.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "5",
        "title": "Patient Brochure",
        "description": "A patient-friendly starter guide to the safety, benefits, and use of COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/patient_brochure.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "6",
        "title": "RESPIMAT Inhaler Training Video",
        "description": "A step-by-step instructional video that details how to prepare, prime, and use the RESPIMAT Inhaler for daily dosing.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/ihi_video.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      }
    ],
    "category": "REP",
    "createdAt": "2015-05-24 12:00:00",
    "openedAt": "2015-05-24 23:27:40",
    "viewedAt": "2015-05-24 22:54:08"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "rep_id": "1",
    "target_id": "1",
    "brands_id": "1",
    "brand_name": "Combivent Respimat",
    "messages_id": "5",
    "message_text": "I would like to schedule a live representative visit.",
    "media": [
      {
        "media_id": "1",
        "title": "Abbreviated Visual Aid",
        "description": "Provides information on key features of COMBIVENT RESPIMAT, including safety and efficacy information, the RESPIMAT Inhaler.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/abbreviated_vis_aid.png",
        "viewedAt": "2015-05-24 23:27:41"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "2",
        "title": "Solutions Plus™ HCP Flashcard",
        "description": "Information about the Solutions Plus phone line that offers support services and education to both patients and HCPs.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/sp_flash_card.png",
        "viewedAt": "2015-05-24 23:27:42"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "3",
        "title": "Solutions Plus™ Patient Flashcard",
        "description": "A detailed list of the services Solutions Plus offers to patients that you can print and give to patients together with a prescription for COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/sp_patient_card.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "4",
        "title": "Abbreviated Instructions for Use",
        "description": "A step-by-step patient guide listing the steps for COMBIVENT RESPIMAT preparation, priming, and dosing, with information on safety and important features of COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/patient_tearsheet.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "5",
        "title": "Patient Brochure",
        "description": "A patient-friendly starter guide to the safety, benefits, and use of COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/patient_brochure.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "6",
        "title": "RESPIMAT Inhaler Training Video",
        "description": "A step-by-step instructional video that details how to prepare, prime, and use the RESPIMAT Inhaler for daily dosing.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/ihi_video.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      }
    ],
    "category": "TARGET",
    "createdAt": "2015-05-24 23:27:40",
    "openedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

**Expected Response**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "rep_id": "1",
    "target_id": "1",
    "brands_id": "1",
    "brand_name": "Combivent Respimat",
    "messages_id": "1",
    "message_text": "Dear [HCP Name],  Thank you for taking the time to speak with me today.  Based on our discussion, I’ve attached additional materials about COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.  I look forward to speaking with you again in the near future.",
    "media": [
      {
        "media_id": "1",
        "title": "Abbreviated Visual Aid",
        "description": "Provides information on key features of COMBIVENT RESPIMAT, including safety and efficacy information, the RESPIMAT Inhaler.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/abbreviated_vis_aid.png",
        "viewedAt": "2015-05-24 23:27:41"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "2",
        "title": "Solutions Plus™ HCP Flashcard",
        "description": "Information about the Solutions Plus phone line that offers support services and education to both patients and HCPs.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/sp_flash_card.png",
        "viewedAt": "2015-05-24 23:27:42"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "3",
        "title": "Solutions Plus™ Patient Flashcard",
        "description": "A detailed list of the services Solutions Plus offers to patients that you can print and give to patients together with a prescription for COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/sp_patient_card.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "4",
        "title": "Abbreviated Instructions for Use",
        "description": "A step-by-step patient guide listing the steps for COMBIVENT RESPIMAT preparation, priming, and dosing, with information on safety and important features of COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/patient_tearsheet.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "5",
        "title": "Patient Brochure",
        "description": "A patient-friendly starter guide to the safety, benefits, and use of COMBIVENT RESPIMAT.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/patient_brochure.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "media_id": "6",
        "title": "RESPIMAT Inhaler Training Video",
        "description": "A step-by-step instructional video that details how to prepare, prime, and use the RESPIMAT Inhaler for daily dosing.",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/ihi_video.png",
        "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      }
    ],
    "category": "REP",
    "createdAt": "2015-05-24 12:00:00",
    "openedAt": "2015-05-24 23:27:40",
    "viewedAt": "2015-05-24 22:54:08"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "rep_id": "1",
    "target_id": "1",
    "brands_id": "1",
    "brand_name": "Combivent Respimat",
    "messages_id": "5",
    "message_text": "I would like to schedule a live representative visit.",
    "media": [],
    "category": "TARGET",
    "createdAt": "2015-05-24 23:27:40",
    "openedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "viewedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end of the first loop, add `unset($media);` This resets the media variable for every iteration of the first loop. PHP is an extremely loose language and once you create a variable, it will exists no matter the scope (in most cases). So second time around in the first loop, the media variable still exists with some data inside and the code sets that variable to an index in the second array.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($entEmail); $i++) {
        $media = [];
        $entMedia = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getAllEmailsMedia($entEmail[$i]['id']);

        for ($j = 0; $j < count($entMedia); $j++) {
            $media[] = [
                "media_id" => $entMedia[$j]['id'],
                "title" => $entMedia[$j]['title'],
                "description" => $entMedia[$j]['description'],
                "thumbnail_url" => $entMedia[$j]['thumbnail_url'],
                "viewedAt" => $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getMediaViewedAt($entEmail[$i]['id'], $entMedia[$j]['id']) ? $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getMediaViewedAt($entEmail[$i]['id'], $entMedia[$j]['id']) : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
            ];
        }

        $response[] = [
            "id" => $entEmail[$i]['id'],
            "rep_id" => $entEmail[$i]['reps_id'],
            "target_id" => $entEmail[$i]['targets_id'],
            "brands_id" => $entEmail[$i]['brands_id'],
            "brand_name" => $entEmail[$i]['name'],
            "messages_id" => $entEmail[$i]['messages_id'],
            "message_text" => $entEmail[$i]['message_text'],
            "media" => $media,
            "category" => $entEmail[$i]['category'],
            "createdAt" => $entEmail[$i]['createdAt'],
            "openedAt" => $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getEmailOpenetAt($entEmail[$i]['id']) ? $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getEmailOpenetAt($entEmail[$i]['id']) : "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "viewedAt" => $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getEmailViewedAt($entEmail[$i]['id']) ? $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->getEmailViewedAt($entEmail[$i]['id']) : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        ];

        unset($media);
    }
```

Comment: How is that? I think I can't do that because that data as you may notice is dynamic so right now it haven't but tomorrow can have, if I `unset($media)` shouldn't be always get `[]`? Can you add some example code?

Comment: This answer should be correct, if in the future you get another item with `count($entMedia) > 0`, $media will be set again.

Comment: @taxicala I am not seeing what `end of first loop` is on my code, can any write a small snippet showing me that?

Comment: Looks like you are getting media based on the $i variable from the first loop. So for index 1, there is some media and hence the array is set and assigned to the response array. However, for index 2 there is no media. Yet the variable $media is already set with index 1's data and is not reset. So it just sets that data in the response.

Comment: @taxicala I did as you suggested and I got this response `Notice: Undefined variable: media (500 Internal Server Error)` so that was my first doubt

Comment: Just added a validation, check if that solves your internal server error.

Comment: @taxicala Nope, same result

Comment: At the beginning of the first loop, add `$media = [];` to initialize. you are getting an error because the variable `$media` does not exists when you put it in the `$response` array because you unset it.

Comment: sorry for that, forgot to write a check. Please check if it works now.

Comment: Didn't realize someone was editing my answer. You do not need all those checks. Those are completely unnecessary. You never need a check around unset and you won't need a check if you just initialize the variable with an empty array.